# Launch Mail app to check for new email

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I know how to launch the Mail app to *write* a new email (using **mailto**). But I have a facility for users who have forgotten their password to get it sent to their email, and when they submit the request I would like to launch the Mail app, preferably in their Inbox.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible, it might be outside the public APIs.  That said, here's an idea that might work, but I don't have all the details for you.  The way you get Mail to open up when you want to send e-mail is that the APIs handle a URL request for mailto: by passing it to Mail.  Maybe you can find another URL type that you can request to have opened, Mail will try to open it, but then have nothing there for Mail to open.  If all goes in your favor, Mail will open and not show anything to the user (even an error from the bogus request you sent it).

Hell if I know what type of URL you'd need a pass, and there's no guarantee that something like this wouldn't break in a future iPhone OS version.

Comment: Yeah it's a good way line of attack. The first question to ask is: is this behavior ever seen in any of Apple's own apps: one app launching Mail for anything else than composing a message? If not, it's highly doubtful that the url would exist.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Confirmed by Apple.

Comment: Can you give the link or quote where Apple confirms this?

Comment: I'd also like to see if they have expressed this explicitly somewhere. Although I guess the fact that they don't *mention* it being possible anywhere would be enough.